# Cannot login with UserAgent

Tags: perl, authentication, forms

I have managed to login with the code below. Now I can do it ony once a day.
And then I cant login, but get the login page in the response.
But when i print `$reqstr` from the code below and paste it to browser(like firefox), I can log in.
Wget doesnt work neiter. Only normal browser.
Soemtimes it seems , that Im logged in, but only get such content:

```
"<html>\cJ<head>\cJ\cI<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"><meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"0\"><meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">\cJ\cI<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL='https://www.address.com/'\">\cJ</head>\cJ</html>\cJ"
```

I also noticed, that while I cant login, Im getting this part in a debugger:

```
_uri_canonical' => URI::https=SCALAR(0x17dad28)
         -> REUSED_ADDRESS
   'handlers' => HASH(0x22dc0c0)
      'response_data' => ARRAY(0x22ee8b8)
         0  HASH(0x22d9a48)
            'callback' => CODE(0x22dba30)
               -> &LWP::UserAgent::__ANON__[/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:682] in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/LWP/UserAgent.pm:679-682
         1  HASH(0x22eea08)
            'callback' => CODE(0x22d9cb8)
               -> &LWP::Protocol::__ANON__[/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/LWP/Protocol.pm:138] in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/LWP/Protocol.pm:135-138
```

Any clue?

Here the code:

```
my $b = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/31.2.0',);


my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
    file => 'lwp_cookies.txt',
    autosave => 1,
    ignore_discard => 1,
);
$cookie_jar->clear;
$cookie_jar->clear_temporary_cookies;
$b->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);
my $url = "https://www.address.com";

my $r = $b->get($url);
$r->decoded_content =~ /FORM ACTION="(.*?)" METHOD/msgi;
my $a = "$url$1";
print $a."\n";
my $reqstr =  $a."&LoginAction=Login&Number=55555&KPassword=passw&UserID=uid";
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $reqstr);
$req->header('Host', 'www.address.com');
$req->header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
$req->header('Connection', 'keep-alive');
$req->header('Accept',  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
my $c = $b->request($req);
```

Comment: The content is a redirect. You can tell by the `meta refresh` tag.  Try following the refresh to the new URL.

Comment: Please see my answers. Since I'm trying (in vain) to get a hat for an accepted answer that isn't upvoted, if one of the answers helps you and you choose to accept it, please be so kind and NOT upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-request that page with the referrer added via `referer()` for `LWP::UserAgent` (or see my second answer if you aren't wedded to that module)

```
sub login { # Code not tested and not really compilable, just a stub for you
    my (@other_args, $url, $referrer_url) = @_;
    # Add your login code from the question, up to calling $b->request()
    $req->referer($referrer_url) if $referrer_url;
    my $c = $b->request($req);
    return $c; # Or return the response?
}

my $result1 = login($original_login_url); #first try
# Obtain the redirect_url from the response.
# If it was a 301 redirect, you can do it via
# my @redirects = $response->redirects();
my $referrer_url = $original_login_url;
my $result2 = login($redirect_url, $referrer_url);
```

References:

- http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/lwp-meta-refresh-tag-handling-63484.html
- http://www.herongyang.com/Perl/LWP-UserAgent-Follow-HTTP-Redirects.html

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't dead set on using `LWP::UserAgent`, use `WWW::Mechanize` instead.

- Best approach: use [`WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::FollowMetaRedirect`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3A%3AMechanize%3A%3APlugin%3A%3AFollowMetaRedirect). The SYNOPSIS is pretty short and to the point:

  ```
  use WWW::Mechanize;
  use WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::FollowMetaRedirect;

  my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
  $mech->get( $url );
  $mech->follow_meta_redirect;

  # Optionally, skip emulating the waiting time
  $mech->follow_meta_redirect( ignore_wait => 1 );
  ```
- If you don't have access to that module, you can create your own, similar to this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=487286

  (Basically, parse the returned content using the regex *shudder* to extract the refresh URL, and get that URL. As per my other answer, you **might** need to add the referrer header)